# Error installing Eric5 on Ubuntu 13.04 (cannot import name Qsci)

Tags: python, ubuntu, pyqt, pyqt4, qscintilla

I've been following the directions [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1865840) to get Eric5 running.

I've built everything from source, but when I try to install Eric, I get this message:

```
patrick@Sat1:~/Downloads/eric5-5.3.6$ sudo python3 install.py
Checking dependencies
Python Version: 3.3.1
Found PyQt4
Found QtHelp
Sorry, please install QScintilla2 and
its PyQt4 wrapper.
Error: cannot import name Qsci
```

However, Qscintilla seems to install just fine. Here's the output from that:

```
patrick@Sat1:~/Downloads/QScintilla-gpl-2.7.2/Python$ sudo python3 configure.py --pyqt=PyQt4
PyQt 4.10.3 is being used.
Qt 4.8.4 is being used.
sip 4.15.2 is being used.
QScintilla 2.7.2 is being used.
The sip executable is /usr/bin/sip.
The QScintilla module will be installed in
/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/PyQt4.
The QScintilla module is being built with 'protected' redefined as 'public'.
The QScintilla .sip files will be installed in /usr/share/sip/PyQt4.
The QScintilla API file will be installed in /usr/share/qt4/api/python.
Generating the C++ source for the Qsci module...
Generating the .pro file for the Qsci module...
Creating the Makefile for the Qsci module...

patrick@Sat1:~/Downloads/QScintilla-gpl-2.7.2/Python$ sudo make all
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -fno-exceptions -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DSIP_PROTECTED_IS_PUBLIC -Dprotected=public -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/python3.3m -I. -o sipQsciQsciLexerMatlab.o sipQsciQsciLexerMatlab.cpp
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -fno-exceptions -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DSIP_PROTECTED_IS_PUBLIC -Dprotected=public -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/python3.3m -I. -o sipQsciQsciLexerHTML.o sipQsciQsciLexerHTML.cpp
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -fno-exceptions -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DSIP_PROTECTED_IS_PUBLIC -Dprotected=public -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/python3.3m -I. -o sipQsciQsciLexerCPP.o sipQsciQsciLexerCPP.cpp
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -fno-exceptions -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DSIP_PROTECTED_IS_PUBLIC -Dprotected=public -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/python3.3m -I. -o sipQsciQsciLexerProperties.o sipQsciQsciLexerProperties.cpp
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -fno-exceptions -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DSIP_PROTECTED_IS_PUBLIC -Dprotected=public -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/python3.3m -I. -o sipQsciQsciLexerPOV.o sipQsciQsciLexerPOV.cpp
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -fno-exceptions -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DSIP_PROTECTED_IS_PUBLIC -Dprotected=public -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/python3.3m -I. -o sipQsciQsciStyledText.o sipQsciQsciStyledText.cpp
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -fno-exceptions -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DSIP_PROTECTED_IS_PUBLIC -Dprotected=public -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/python3.3m -I. -o sipQsciQsciLexerPascal.o sipQsciQsciLexerPascal.cpp
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -fno-exceptions -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DSIP_PROTECTED_IS_PUBLIC -Dprotected=public -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/python3.3m -I. -o sipQsciQsciLexerTCL.o sipQsciQsciLexerTCL.cpp
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -fno-exceptions -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DSIP_PROTECTED_IS_PUBLIC -Dprotected=public -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/python3.3m -I. -o sipQscicmodule.o sipQscicmodule.cpp
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -fno-exceptions -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DSIP_PROTECTED_IS_PUBLIC -Dprotected=public -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/python3.3m -I. -o sipQsciQsciPrinter.o sipQsciQsciPrinter.cpp
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -fno-exceptions -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DSIP_PROTECTED_IS_PUBLIC -Dprotected=public -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/python3.3m -I. -o sipQsciQsciLexerFortran.o sipQsciQsciLexerFortran.cpp
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -fno-exceptions -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DSIP_PROTECTED_IS_PUBLIC -Dprotected=public -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/python3.3m -I. -o sipQsciQsciAPIs.o sipQsciQsciAPIs.cpp
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -fno-exceptions -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DSIP_PROTECTED_IS_PUBLIC -Dprotected=public -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/python3.3m -I. -o sipQsciQsciLexerBatch.o sipQsciQsciLexerBatch.cpp
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -fno-exceptions -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DSIP_PROTECTED_IS_PUBLIC -Dprotected=public -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/python3.3m -I. -o sipQsciQsciLexerJava.o sipQsciQsciLexerJava.cpp
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -fno-exceptions -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DSIP_PROTECTED_IS_PUBLIC -Dprotected=public -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/python3.3m -I. -o sipQsciQsciLexerDiff.o sipQsciQsciLexerDiff.cpp
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -fno-exceptions -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DSIP_PROTECTED_IS_PUBLIC -Dprotected=public -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/python3.3m -I. -o sipQsciQsciLexerYAML.o sipQsciQsciLexerYAML.cpp
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -fno-exceptions -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DSIP_PROTECTED_IS_PUBLIC -Dprotected=public -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/python3.3m -I. -o sipQsciQsciLexerCSS.o sipQsciQsciLexerCSS.cpp
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -fno-exceptions -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DSIP_PROTECTED_IS_PUBLIC -Dprotected=public -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/python3.3m -I. -o sipQsciQsciMacro.o sipQsciQsciMacro.cpp
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -fno-exceptions -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DSIP_PROTECTED_IS_PUBLIC -Dprotected=public -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/python3.3m -I. -o sipQsciQsciLexerCustom.o sipQsciQsciLexerCustom.cpp
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -fno-exceptions -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DSIP_PROTECTED_IS_PUBLIC -Dprotected=public -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/python3.3m -I. -o sipQsciQsciLexerOctave.o sipQsciQsciLexerOctave.cpp
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -fno-exceptions -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DSIP_PROTECTED_IS_PUBLIC -Dprotected=public -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/python3.3m -I. -o sipQsciQsciLexerD.o sipQsciQsciLexerD.cpp
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -fno-exceptions -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DSIP_PROTECTED_IS_PUBLIC -Dprotected=public -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/python3.3m -I. -o sipQsciQsciLexerLua.o sipQsciQsciLexerLua.cpp
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -fno-exceptions -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DSIP_PROTECTED_IS_PUBLIC -Dprotected=public -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/python3.3m -I. -o sipQsciQsciScintillaBase.o sipQsciQsciScintillaBase.cpp
./sipQsciQsciScintillaBase.cpp:3182:1: warning: narrowing conversion of ‘(QsciScintillaBase::._304)4261412864u’ from ‘unsigned int’ to ‘int’ inside { } is ill-formed in C++11 [-Wnarrowing]
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -fno-exceptions -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DSIP_PROTECTED_IS_PUBLIC -Dprotected=public -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/python3.3m -I. -o sipQsciQsciLexerXML.o sipQsciQsciLexerXML.cpp
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -fno-exceptions -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DSIP_PROTECTED_IS_PUBLIC -Dprotected=public -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/python3.3m -I. -o sipQsciQsciStyle.o sipQsciQsciStyle.cpp
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -fno-exceptions -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DSIP_PROTECTED_IS_PUBLIC -Dprotected=public -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/python3.3m -I. -o sipQsciQsciLexerFortran77.o sipQsciQsciLexerFortran77.cpp
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -fno-exceptions -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DSIP_PROTECTED_IS_PUBLIC -Dprotected=public -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/python3.3m -I. -o sipQsciQsciLexerTeX.o sipQsciQsciLexerTeX.cpp
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -fno-exceptions -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DSIP_PROTECTED_IS_PUBLIC -Dprotected=public -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/python3.3m -I. -o sipQsciQsciLexerCMake.o sipQsciQsciLexerCMake.cpp
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -fno-exceptions -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DSIP_PROTECTED_IS_PUBLIC -Dprotected=public -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/python3.3m -I. -o sipQsciQsciCommandSet.o sipQsciQsciCommandSet.cpp
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -fno-exceptions -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DSIP_PROTECTED_IS_PUBLIC -Dprotected=public -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/python3.3m -I. -o sipQsciQsciDocument.o sipQsciQsciDocument.cpp
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -fno-exceptions -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DSIP_PROTECTED_IS_PUBLIC -Dprotected=public -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/python3.3m -I. -o sipQsciQsciScintilla.o sipQsciQsciScintilla.cpp
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -fno-exceptions -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DSIP_PROTECTED_IS_PUBLIC -Dprotected=public -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/python3.3m -I. -o sipQsciQsciLexerPostScript.o sipQsciQsciLexerPostScript.cpp
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -fno-exceptions -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DSIP_PROTECTED_IS_PUBLIC -Dprotected=public -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/python3.3m -I. -o sipQsciQsciLexerPython.o sipQsciQsciLexerPython.cpp
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -fno-exceptions -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DSIP_PROTECTED_IS_PUBLIC -Dprotected=public -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/python3.3m -I. -o sipQsciQList0100QsciStyledText.o sipQsciQList0100QsciStyledText.cpp
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -fno-exceptions -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DSIP_PROTECTED_IS_PUBLIC -Dprotected=public -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/python3.3m -I. -o sipQsciQsciLexerCSharp.o sipQsciQsciLexerCSharp.cpp
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -fno-exceptions -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DSIP_PROTECTED_IS_PUBLIC -Dprotected=public -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/python3.3m -I. -o sipQsciQsciLexerVHDL.o sipQsciQsciLexerVHDL.cpp
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -fno-exceptions -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DSIP_PROTECTED_IS_PUBLIC -Dprotected=public -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/python3.3m -I. -o sipQsciQsciLexerVerilog.o sipQsciQsciLexerVerilog.cpp
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -fno-exceptions -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DSIP_PROTECTED_IS_PUBLIC -Dprotected=public -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/python3.3m -I. -o sipQsciQList0101QsciCommand.o sipQsciQList0101QsciCommand.cpp
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -fno-exceptions -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DSIP_PROTECTED_IS_PUBLIC -Dprotected=public -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/python3.3m -I. -o sipQsciQsciLexerSQL.o sipQsciQsciLexerSQL.cpp
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -fno-exceptions -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DSIP_PROTECTED_IS_PUBLIC -Dprotected=public -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/python3.3m -I. -o sipQsciQsciLexerIDL.o sipQsciQsciLexerIDL.cpp
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -fno-exceptions -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DSIP_PROTECTED_IS_PUBLIC -Dprotected=public -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/python3.3m -I. -o sipQsciQsciLexerRuby.o sipQsciQsciLexerRuby.cpp
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -fno-exceptions -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DSIP_PROTECTED_IS_PUBLIC -Dprotected=public -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/python3.3m -I. -o sipQsciQsciLexerJavaScript.o sipQsciQsciLexerJavaScript.cpp
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -fno-exceptions -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DSIP_PROTECTED_IS_PUBLIC -Dprotected=public -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/python3.3m -I. -o sipQsciQsciLexerSpice.o sipQsciQsciLexerSpice.cpp
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -fno-exceptions -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DSIP_PROTECTED_IS_PUBLIC -Dprotected=public -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/python3.3m -I. -o sipQsciQsciLexer.o sipQsciQsciLexer.cpp
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -fno-exceptions -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DSIP_PROTECTED_IS_PUBLIC -Dprotected=public -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/python3.3m -I. -o sipQsciQsciCommand.o sipQsciQsciCommand.cpp
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -fno-exceptions -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DSIP_PROTECTED_IS_PUBLIC -Dprotected=public -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/python3.3m -I. -o sipQsciQsciAbstractAPIs.o sipQsciQsciAbstractAPIs.cpp
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -fno-exceptions -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DSIP_PROTECTED_IS_PUBLIC -Dprotected=public -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/python3.3m -I. -o sipQsciQsciLexerPerl.o sipQsciQsciLexerPerl.cpp
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -fno-exceptions -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DSIP_PROTECTED_IS_PUBLIC -Dprotected=public -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/python3.3m -I. -o sipQsciQsciLexerMakefile.o sipQsciQsciLexerMakefile.cpp
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -fno-exceptions -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DSIP_PROTECTED_IS_PUBLIC -Dprotected=public -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/python3.3m -I. -o sipQsciQsciLexerBash.o sipQsciQsciLexerBash.cpp
rm -f libQsci.so
g++ -m64 -Wl,--version-script=Qsci.exp -Wl,-O1 -shared -o libQsci.so sipQsciQsciLexerMatlab.o sipQsciQsciLexerHTML.o sipQsciQsciLexerCPP.o sipQsciQsciLexerProperties.o sipQsciQsciLexerPOV.o sipQsciQsciStyledText.o sipQsciQsciLexerPascal.o sipQsciQsciLexerTCL.o sipQscicmodule.o sipQsciQsciPrinter.o sipQsciQsciLexerFortran.o sipQsciQsciAPIs.o sipQsciQsciLexerBatch.o sipQsciQsciLexerJava.o sipQsciQsciLexerDiff.o sipQsciQsciLexerYAML.o sipQsciQsciLexerCSS.o sipQsciQsciMacro.o sipQsciQsciLexerCustom.o sipQsciQsciLexerOctave.o sipQsciQsciLexerD.o sipQsciQsciLexerLua.o sipQsciQsciScintillaBase.o sipQsciQsciLexerXML.o sipQsciQsciStyle.o sipQsciQsciLexerFortran77.o sipQsciQsciLexerTeX.o sipQsciQsciLexerCMake.o sipQsciQsciCommandSet.o sipQsciQsciDocument.o sipQsciQsciScintilla.o sipQsciQsciLexerPostScript.o sipQsciQsciLexerPython.o sipQsciQList0100QsciStyledText.o sipQsciQsciLexerCSharp.o sipQsciQsciLexerVHDL.o sipQsciQsciLexerVerilog.o sipQsciQList0101QsciCommand.o sipQsciQsciLexerSQL.o sipQsciQsciLexerIDL.o sipQsciQsciLexerRuby.o sipQsciQsciLexerJavaScript.o sipQsciQsciLexerSpice.o sipQsciQsciLexer.o sipQsciQsciCommand.o sipQsciQsciAbstractAPIs.o sipQsciQsciLexerPerl.o sipQsciQsciLexerMakefile.o sipQsciQsciLexerBash.o   -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lqscintilla2 -lQtGui -lQtCore -lpthread  
cp -f libQsci.so Qsci.so

patrick@Sat1:~/Downloads/QScintilla-gpl-2.7.2/Python$ sudo make install
install -m 755 -p /home/patrick/Downloads/QScintilla-gpl-2.7.2/Python/Qsci.so /usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/PyQt4/
strip /usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/PyQt4/Qsci.so
install -m 644 -p /home/patrick/Downloads/QScintilla-gpl-2.7.2/Python/QScintilla2.api /usr/share/qt4/api/python/
install -m 644 -p /home/patrick/Downloads/QScintilla-gpl-2.7.2/Python/sip/qscilexerfortran77.sip /usr/share/sip/PyQt4/Qsci/
install -m 644 -p /home/patrick/Downloads/QScintilla-gpl-2.7.2/Python/sip/qscilexerpascal.sip /usr/share/sip/PyQt4/Qsci/
install -m 644 -p /home/patrick/Downloads/QScintilla-gpl-2.7.2/Python/sip/qscilexertex.sip /usr/share/sip/PyQt4/Qsci/
install -m 644 -p /home/patrick/Downloads/QScintilla-gpl-2.7.2/Python/sip/qsciscintillabase4.sip /usr/share/sip/PyQt4/Qsci/
install -m 644 -p /home/patrick/Downloads/QScintilla-gpl-2.7.2/Python/sip/qscilexerjava.sip /usr/share/sip/PyQt4/Qsci/
install -m 644 -p /home/patrick/Downloads/QScintilla-gpl-2.7.2/Python/sip/qscilexerxml.sip /usr/share/sip/PyQt4/Qsci/
install -m 644 -p /home/patrick/Downloads/QScintilla-gpl-2.7.2/Python/sip/qscilexerdiff.sip /usr/share/sip/PyQt4/Qsci/
install -m 644 -p /home/patrick/Downloads/QScintilla-gpl-2.7.2/Python/sip/qscilexercustom.sip /usr/share/sip/PyQt4/Qsci/
install -m 644 -p /home/patrick/Downloads/QScintilla-gpl-2.7.2/Python/sip/qscimod5.sip /usr/share/sip/PyQt4/Qsci/
install -m 644 -p /home/patrick/Downloads/QScintilla-gpl-2.7.2/Python/sip/qsciapis.sip /usr/share/sip/PyQt4/Qsci/
install -m 644 -p /home/patrick/Downloads/QScintilla-gpl-2.7.2/Python/sip/qsciabstractapis.sip /usr/share/sip/PyQt4/Qsci/
install -m 644 -p /home/patrick/Downloads/QScintilla-gpl-2.7.2/Python/sip/qscicommandset.sip /usr/share/sip/PyQt4/Qsci/
install -m 644 -p /home/patrick/Downloads/QScintilla-gpl-2.7.2/Python/sip/qscilexerhtml.sip /usr/share/sip/PyQt4/Qsci/
install -m 644 -p /home/patrick/Downloads/QScintilla-gpl-2.7.2/Python/sip/qscilexerpython.sip /usr/share/sip/PyQt4/Qsci/
install -m 644 -p /home/patrick/Downloads/QScintilla-gpl-2.7.2/Python/sip/qscilexertcl.sip /usr/share/sip/PyQt4/Qsci/
install -m 644 -p /home/patrick/Downloads/QScintilla-gpl-2.7.2/Python/sip/qscilexerfortran.sip /usr/share/sip/PyQt4/Qsci/
install -m 644 -p /home/patrick/Downloads/QScintilla-gpl-2.7.2/Python/sip/qscilexersql.sip /usr/share/sip/PyQt4/Qsci/
install -m 644 -p /home/patrick/Downloads/QScintilla-gpl-2.7.2/Python/sip/qscilexerpostscript.sip /usr/share/sip/PyQt4/Qsci/
install -m 644 -p /home/patrick/Downloads/QScintilla-gpl-2.7.2/Python/sip/qsciscintillabase3.sip /usr/share/sip/PyQt4/Qsci/
install -m 644 -p /home/patrick/Downloads/QScintilla-gpl-2.7.2/Python/sip/qscimacro.sip /usr/share/sip/PyQt4/Qsci/
install -m 644 -p /home/patrick/Downloads/QScintilla-gpl-2.7.2/Python/sip/qscilexervhdl.sip /usr/share/sip/PyQt4/Qsci/
install -m 644 -p /home/patrick/Downloads/QScintilla-gpl-2.7.2/Python/sip/qscistyledtext.sip /usr/share/sip/PyQt4/Qsci/
install -m 644 -p /home/patrick/Downloads/QScintilla-gpl-2.7.2/Python/sip/qscilexerperl.sip /usr/share/sip/PyQt4/Qsci/
install -m 644 -p /home/patrick/Downloads/QScintilla-gpl-2.7.2/Python/sip/qscimod3.sip /usr/share/sip/PyQt4/Qsci/
install -m 644 -p /home/patrick/Downloads/QScintilla-gpl-2.7.2/Python/sip/qscimod4.sip /usr/share/sip/PyQt4/Qsci/
install -m 644 -p /home/patrick/Downloads/QScintilla-gpl-2.7.2/Python/sip/qscilexercsharp.sip /usr/share/sip/PyQt4/Qsci/
install -m 644 -p /home/patrick/Downloads/QScintilla-gpl-2.7.2/Python/sip/qsciscintilla.sip /usr/share/sip/PyQt4/Qsci/
install -m 644 -p /home/patrick/Downloads/QScintilla-gpl-2.7.2/Python/sip/qscilexerjavascript.sip /usr/share/sip/PyQt4/Qsci/
install -m 644 -p /home/patrick/Downloads/QScintilla-gpl-2.7.2/Python/sip/qsciprinter.sip /usr/share/sip/PyQt4/Qsci/
install -m 644 -p /home/patrick/Downloads/QScintilla-gpl-2.7.2/Python/sip/qscistyle.sip /usr/share/sip/PyQt4/Qsci/
install -m 644 -p /home/patrick/Downloads/QScintilla-gpl-2.7.2/Python/sip/qscilexercmake.sip /usr/share/sip/PyQt4/Qsci/
install -m 644 -p /home/patrick/Downloads/QScintilla-gpl-2.7.2/Python/sip/qscilexer.sip /usr/share/sip/PyQt4/Qsci/
install -m 644 -p /home/patrick/Downloads/QScintilla-gpl-2.7.2/Python/sip/qscidocument.sip /usr/share/sip/PyQt4/Qsci/
install -m 644 -p /home/patrick/Downloads/QScintilla-gpl-2.7.2/Python/sip/qscilexerverilog.sip /usr/share/sip/PyQt4/Qsci/
install -m 644 -p /home/patrick/Downloads/QScintilla-gpl-2.7.2/Python/sip/qscilexeridl.sip /usr/share/sip/PyQt4/Qsci/
install -m 644 -p /home/patrick/Downloads/QScintilla-gpl-2.7.2/Python/sip/qscilexerbatch.sip /usr/share/sip/PyQt4/Qsci/
install -m 644 -p /home/patrick/Downloads/QScintilla-gpl-2.7.2/Python/sip/qscilexerproperties.sip /usr/share/sip/PyQt4/Qsci/
install -m 644 -p /home/patrick/Downloads/QScintilla-gpl-2.7.2/Python/sip/qscilexerlua.sip /usr/share/sip/PyQt4/Qsci/
install -m 644 -p /home/patrick/Downloads/QScintilla-gpl-2.7.2/Python/sip/qscimodcommon.sip /usr/share/sip/PyQt4/Qsci/
install -m 644 -p /home/patrick/Downloads/QScintilla-gpl-2.7.2/Python/sip/qscilexerbash.sip /usr/share/sip/PyQt4/Qsci/
install -m 644 -p /home/patrick/Downloads/QScintilla-gpl-2.7.2/Python/sip/qscilexeroctave.sip /usr/share/sip/PyQt4/Qsci/
install -m 644 -p /home/patrick/Downloads/QScintilla-gpl-2.7.2/Python/sip/qscilexermatlab.sip /usr/share/sip/PyQt4/Qsci/
install -m 644 -p /home/patrick/Downloads/QScintilla-gpl-2.7.2/Python/sip/qscicommand.sip /usr/share/sip/PyQt4/Qsci/
install -m 644 -p /home/patrick/Downloads/QScintilla-gpl-2.7.2/Python/sip/qscilexercss.sip /usr/share/sip/PyQt4/Qsci/
install -m 644 -p /home/patrick/Downloads/QScintilla-gpl-2.7.2/Python/sip/qscilexermakefile.sip /usr/share/sip/PyQt4/Qsci/
install -m 644 -p /home/patrick/Downloads/QScintilla-gpl-2.7.2/Python/sip/qscilexeryaml.sip /usr/share/sip/PyQt4/Qsci/
install -m 644 -p /home/patrick/Downloads/QScintilla-gpl-2.7.2/Python/sip/qscilexerpov.sip /usr/share/sip/PyQt4/Qsci/
install -m 644 -p /home/patrick/Downloads/QScintilla-gpl-2.7.2/Python/sip/qscilexercpp.sip /usr/share/sip/PyQt4/Qsci/
install -m 644 -p /home/patrick/Downloads/QScintilla-gpl-2.7.2/Python/sip/qscilexerruby.sip /usr/share/sip/PyQt4/Qsci/
install -m 644 -p /home/patrick/Downloads/QScintilla-gpl-2.7.2/Python/sip/qscilexerspice.sip /usr/share/sip/PyQt4/Qsci/
install -m 644 -p /home/patrick/Downloads/QScintilla-gpl-2.7.2/Python/sip/qscilexerd.sip /usr/share/sip/PyQt4/Qsci/
```

Running IPython and trying to use `from PyQt4 import Qsci` also causes an `ImportError`.

I'm not sure what to do since nothing raises any errors while installing, and I haven't missed any steps. What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you added `/usr/share/sip` to your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable?

Do you have a good reason not to use the existing packages? It will make maintenance/upgrading/installing other packages with dependencies a lot simpler.

```
[chickpea ~/src/python]$ sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt4.qsci
...

The following extra packages will be installed:
  libqscintilla2-9 libqscintilla2-translations
The following NEW packages will be installed:
 libqscintilla2-9 libqscintilla2-translations python3-pyqt4.qsci
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove
...

[chickpea ~/src/python]$ ipython3
[python/ 1 ]& from PyQt4 import Qsci
[python/ 2 ]& Qsci.QSCINTILLA_VERSION_STR
     Out[2]: '2.7.1'
```

Comment: I don't have any good reason to not use the existing packages, I just didn't know that they existed because all of the documentation that I've read suggests that you need to build if from source. I got past that step, but I'm now getting `RuntimeError: the sip module implements API v9.0 to v9.2 but the PyQt4.QtSql module requires API v10.1`. `apt-get` and `pip` both tell me that sip is at the latest version. Any suggestions?

Comment: Where are you getting that message? Hard to tell what's going on from what's here, but it sounds like you compiled some of it by hand, and it's not compatible with the ubuntu-distributed libraries.

Comment: I would suggest:

1. Try and install everything from the ubuntu packages. They should all be compatible and this will be much easier. There are packages called `python3-sip` and `python3-pyqt4.qtsql`. Then either uninstall your own versions or make sure `PATH` and `PYTHONPATH` point to the standard places.

2. Rebuild/install whatever you built yourself against the newly installed Ubuntu packages.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem by:
sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt4.qsci ipython3 python-qScintilla2

My environment is ubuntu 12.04 64bits.